# File.Delete after File.Copy

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have below copy and delete one after another. Delete complains that f1 is still being used (probably copy operation is still not yet completed) .Any idea how to fix this issue?

```
 File.Copy(f1, f2, True)
 File.Delete(f1)
```

Comment: why not just use a move operation that performs it all for you?

Comment: Copy is synchronous operation, your program does not proceed to delete before the copy is finished. Have you opened the file in your application prior to this and forgot to close it?

Comment: @Esa: I haven't opened the file after copy. It still complains!

Comment: @NagarajS What is the difference in that post and OP's code?

Comment: For testing: Try to insert a Thread.Sleep(200) between those operations. I am remembering some issues with file operations on windows. While the method calls are sync as @Esa stated, the operation on OS level may indeed delay some time. We've experienced this behaviour in unit tests where a high rate of create/deletes are done and sometimes fail.

Comment: @codematrix We can see that you haven't opened the file after the copy. Are you opening it before the copy?

Answer (score 0):

This works without any problems for me.

```
    String f1 = "d:\\temp\\f1", f2 = "d:\\temp\\f2";
    File.Copy(f1, f2, true);
    File.Delete(f1);
```

I'd suggest trying to use Process Monitor - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx to see if the system has locked the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the file f1 is open for reading by some other code.  A prime suspect being anti-virus software.